# back to previous page after page refresh more then one time JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I go back to previous page after refresh current page more then one times, i.e when I doing so then it will result in the current page. To do so I have to use my back button twice. I tried `window.history.back()` and `window.history.go(-1)`, but not works.

Answer (score 0):

Save the current page url in a cookie when the document is ready:

```
$(function(){
  var prev = $.cookie("previousUrl");
  if (prev !=window.location.href)
    $.cookie("previousUrl", window.location.href, {path:"/"});
});
```

And then use the cookie for going back to previous url:

```
function goBack()
{
    var prev = $.cookie("previousUrl");
    window.history.go(prev)
}
```

Hope this will help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
function goBack() {
    window.history.back();
}
```

Also you can refer in [GoBack](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_his_back.asp) link.